# How do I fetch a web response to use as a variable in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So I have a tag in my HTML where onclick calls a JavaScript script, and passes a number to it:

```
<svg id="fillgauge1" onclick="gauge1.update(42);"></svg>
```

But I also have a web service that streams a number back to me (as text/plain):

```
http://myserver/stream?GetNumber&token=xyz
```

What I want is to be able to do is take the result of that service, and pass it to the JavaScript, sort of like this:

```
<svg id="fillgauge1" onclick="gauge1.update(http://myserver/stream?GetNumber&token=xyz);"></svg>
```

But, obviously, it isn't as simple as that!

I guess I'm asking a couple of things. Is there a way to retrieve the value like this, within the HTML, or should the operation go into the JavaScript? And if it should go into the JavaScript, what technique or commands do I use? I'm fairly inexperienced (which I'm sure shows) but I can research what to do if I can just get some pointers. My Googling just isn't finding what approach to take, so I'm kind of lost, and any suggestions would be appreciated.

To clarify the scenario, I have an SVG object with a number label on it. The user clicking the object causes the number to update. I can make it update to a fixed value, but I'd like to get that number, live, from a web service. I can easily change that service from serving text/plain to XML or JSON if that's a better technique.

Comment: You should look into the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Comment: Fetch API. Thanks. Will do.